# Are these figaro configuration settings correct for heroku deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to store my secret twitter, and Facebook oauth keys so I can deploy to Heroku properly. I'd just like to confirm that I am doing it right.

In my application.yml (generated by figaro):

```
// Add application configuration variables here, as shown below.
//

// PUSHER_APP_ID: "2954"
// PUSHER_KEY: 7381a978f7dd7f9a1117
// PUSHER_SECRET: abdc3b896a0ffb85d373
// STRIPE_API_KEY: EdAvEPVEC3LuaTg5Q3z6WbDVqZlcBQ8Z
// STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: pk_BRgD57O8fHja9HxduJUszhef6jCyS
// note these are arbitrary keys for the stack overflow

FR_FACEBOOK_KEY=1231231233123123
FR_FACEBOOK_SECRET=3123123123123
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=12312312312312
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=1312312312312
```

So that's the application.yml, then I simply need to run:

```
 heroku config:add FR_FACEBOOK_KEY=8926 // and so on...
```

correct?

Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advanced!

When I run rake figaro:heroku I'm getting this error:

```
[new_work]$rake figaro:heroku
rake aborted!
undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x007fbdc6c0e2a8>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:39:in `flatten'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'
/Users/usr/Sites/new_work/config/application.rb:22:in `<module:Friendiose>'
/Users/usr/Sites/new_work/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/usr/Sites/new_work/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/usr/Sites/new_work/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember to use `:` instead of `=` to separate your keys and values. You can access the keys from your rails app using `ENV["KEY_NAME"]`

However, you do not have to `heroku config:add` keys while you have Figaro, just use `rake figaro:heroku` as explained here https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: thanks @Andreas when I run that rake command I am getting an error, I've updated the post with it.

Comment: Ah yes, I just noticed that you had `=` instead of `:` :P, was that it?