# Rails 4: Unable to protect data using Figaro gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

creating an app using the twitter api , i have the relevant codes
but when i want to using figaro gem to protect i get errors when typing rake figaro:heroku

```
rake figaro:heroku
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x007ff074af1010>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:39:in `flatten'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'
/Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/tweetscope/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Tweetscope>'
/Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/tweetscope/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/tweetscope/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

keyword.rb file

```
def grab_twitts
      client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "2DZcdTw4p1m2yU18xxxxxxxxx"
      config.consumer_secret     = <%= ENV["CONFIG.CONSUMER_SECRET"] %>
      config.access_token        = "71875314-xPOGuWIU7CiDcR3Vx9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      config.access_token_secret = <%= ENV["CONFIG.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"] %>
    end
```

installed figaro gem & added the following information to the application.yml

```
CONFIG.CONSUMER_SECRET     = "whpCvjNmePXzj6iSfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
CONFIG.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "1P00CJmiQ7Tqhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

after removing the = to : now getting aonther error

Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/tweetscope/app/models/keyword.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end ...g.access_token_secret: <%= ENV["CONFIG.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"... ... ^ /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/tweetscope/app/models/keyword.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected '>' /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/tweetscope/app/models/keyword.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :tweets

    def grab_twitts
      client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key "2DZcdTw4pvccccccccccccc"
      config.consumer_secret <%= ENV["CONFIG.CONSUMER_SECRET"] %>
      config.access_token "71875314-xPOGuWIU7CiDcR3Vx9pkJbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
      config.access_token_secret:  <%= ENV["CONFIG.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"] %>
    end

    client.search(self.word, :count => 10, :result_type => "recent").take(10).collect do |tweet|
        new_tweet = Tweet.new

        new_tweet.tweet_id = tweet.id.to_s
        new_tweet.tweet_created_at = tweet.created_at
        new_tweet.text = tweet.text


        new_tweet.user_uid = tweet.user.id
        new_tweet.user_name = tweet.user.name
        new_tweet.user_screen_name = tweet.user.screen_name
        new_tweet.user_image_url = tweet.user.profile_image_url.to_s


        new_tweet.keyword = self

        new_tweet.save

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `:` instead of `=` in `application.yml` as suggested in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20477546/2622934)?

Comment: yes now getting a new error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are accessing the values from somewhere like `database.yml` you need the `<%= ... %>` syntax.  But when you are in a model you should leave that out.  Try:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "2DZcdTw4pvccccccccccccc"
  config.consumer_secret = ENV["CONFIG.CONSUMER_SECRET"]
  config.access_token = "71875314-xPOGuWIU7CiDcR3Vx9pkJbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
  config.access_token_secret = ENV["CONFIG.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

application.yml (and YAML files in general) key-value pairs need to be formatted like this:

```
CONFIG.CONSUMER_SECRET: "whpCvjNmePXzj6iSfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
CONFIG.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: "1P00CJmiQ7Tqhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I.E. with Javascript Object notation.  You're using `=` instead, and I think that's what's causing figaro to break.

Comment: hi thanks tried this but got error message which i have updated